# remove line comment from file by using regex

Tags: c++, regex

I used the pattern below to remove comment lines from file, and succeed it in Visual Studio Editor. However, the same pattern didn't work with C++ regex class.

```
std::regex pattern ("#.*\n");
fullText =  std::regex_replace (fullText,pattern,"");
```

Code above is a very brief part from the implementation: You can assume all text is read into `fullText` at once.

Actual results must remove all comment lines from file/string. Trailing comments can be ignored.

Sample file is .txt extension and has the text below:

```
# Initialization file..
# This file supports line comments, and does not support trailing comments.
# Text here is not case sensitive.
# White spaces are ignored in file processing. 
# Values are comma "," separated. 


Colmn,          Colmn,  
1,              0xFF,
2,              0xFF, 
3,              0xFF,
4,              0xFF,
5,              0xFF,
```

I assume all lines must be finished with `\n`, and I attempt to select all text between `#` and `\n`.

Thanks in advance for the any advice.

Comment: Please provide the sample text it fails on. BTW, the last `\n` should be optional to match the comment on the last line of text, `"#.*\n?"`. Also, try `"#.*[\r\n]*"`

Comment: Try escaping the backslah: `("#.*\\n");`

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: It worked for me.  I used `auto fullText = string("#one two\nthree four\n#five six\nseven eight\nnine #ten\n");`

Comment: Some issues to think about:  1) `char t[] = "//";` is not a commented line; 2) `/* double backslashes: // */` uses C-Style comments and the "//" is not the start of a comment; 3) Similarly, `char u[] = "/* not a comment */";` is not a comment.  Regular expressions may not be the correct choice for parsing comments.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, {"#.*[\r\n]*"} worked. Could you elaborate what was wrong before

Comment: `\n` does not match CR chars. `\r` does. And `.` does not match carriage returns in the ECMAScript 5 compliant regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is that `.` does not match carriage returns in the ECMAScript 5 compliant regex and `\n` pattern does not match CR chars while `\r` does.

You may fix the issue by using `[\r\n]*` at the end of the pattern:

```
std::regex pattern{"#.*[\r\n]*"};
```

Comment: Thanks, well explained!